# What exactly is the mechanism of "nascent hydrogen"?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, redox

I put the quotes because Wikipedia says it's an outdated theory.

What exactly happens when nitrobenzene is converted to aniline using $\ce{Sn/conc HCl}$?

According to a few books which haven't been updated, even $\ce{Na}$/ethanol, $\ce{Zn/dil H2SO4}$ produce this. I guess a metal may have an important role in the actual mechanism.

Is there any specific reason why  $\ce{Na}$/ethanol is used to reduce cyanides to amines, and $\ce{Sn/conc HCl}$ to reduce nitrobenzene? (and not the other way around)

Even $\ce{KMnO4}$ produces "nascent oxygen"? What exactly is going on?

Comment: Which question are you asking? Currently there's three `?` marks in your post (excluding the one in your title) :( As for the middle one, I was taught that tin+conc HCl will reduce cyanide to amine, but then _further reduce_ it to aldehydes because it is in an aqueous medium. A similar thing won't happen with sodium/ethanol (alcoholic medium). I am not sure of the exact mechanism though.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/42549/acids-generating-nascent-gas-atoms https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/24726/aqua-regia-and-nascent-chlorine?s=2|45.1855